# Python 3.7 Variable Chained Method Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've run into a similar problem as referenced here - [Dynamic Method Call In Python 2.7 using strings of method names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734618/dynamic-method-call-in-python-2-7-using-strings-of-method-names)

Here's an example of what my working method call looks like, the method at the end is based on a given data type, in this case `.string_value`:

```
tag.fields[field["key"]].string_value = field["value"]
```

However I won't always be assigning just strings as there are methods for other data types. I attempted a solution similar to the one referenced in the linked thread:

```
typer = getattr(datacatalog_v1.types.TagField, f"{field['type']}_value")
tag.fields[field["key"]].typer = field["value"]
```

With `typer` being my new dynamic method call, but it's not working. I'm receiving this as an error - `'TagField' object has no attribute 'typer'`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana Apologies. Expanded on the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite interesting. I'm not sure what package/datatype ur working on, however it looks like you have 2 issues.

First, getattr returns a string, and you can't call a string, e.g. 'python'()

Second, if you remove the () after getattr(), typer will be a string data, and you cant use it like that. In

```
tag.fields[field["key"]].typer
```

typer must be a method/attribute of some sort rather than string. The best way is to build if statement or dict, combine different value of typer with different method/attribute calls.

```
type_methods = {'string_value': tag.fields[field["key"]].string_value, 
                'int_value': tag.fields[field["key"]].int_value, 
                'json_value': tag.fields[field["key"]].json_value} 
typer = getattr(datacatalog_v1.types.TagField, f"{field['type']}_value")
type_method[type] = field["value"]
```

---

update:

There is a setattr(object, name, value) function

```
typer = getattr(datacatalog_v1.types.TagField, f"{field['type']}_value")
setattr(tag.fields[field['key']], typer, field['value'])
```

Comment: you modified ur question and removed () as I typed this XD, however second part should explain the 'TagField' object has no attribute 'typer' issue

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I see how your first solution would work, but there's got to be a simpler way than redefining all of the data type-specific methods. For reference I'm working with the Google Cloud Data Catalog API - https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/index.html

Comment: you reminded me, there is a setattr you can try. keep the typer = getattr() and do setattr(tag.fields[field["key"]], typer, field["value"]). Try and see if it works

Comment: This worked! setattr(tag.fields[field["key"]], f"{field['type']}_value", field["value"])